# Unrestricted grammar

Tags: grammar

What does this general grammar do?

```
S -> LR 
L -> L0Y 
L -> LX 
X1 -> 1X 
X0 -> 0X 
X0 -> 1Y 
Y1 -> 0Y 
YR -> R     
L  -> epsilon 
R  -> epsilon
```

the start symbol is S. I tried to generate string from this grammar and I got every binary numbers. but I think it does something specific.

Comment: Context? Where did you get that grammar?

Comment: this is from one of the practice set.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a rule that deletes trailing `x`. How did you get to the binary numbers?

Comment: X0 does generates 1Y and then it disappears. you could easily verify generating 0, 00 etc.

Comment: What is the goal? Find the meaning of it? Find the associated language?

Comment: Describe L(G) in English using no more than four words.

Comment: `0` and `1` are the only terminals here? You need to define that. I assumed all were terminals.

Comment: You already do have the language. Are you trying to prove your observation?

Comment: Yes 0,1 are the only terminals here. I doubt it generates all binary strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
S -> LR 
L -> L0Y 
L -> LX 
X1 -> 1X 
X0 -> 0X 
X0 -> 1Y 
Y1 -> 0Y 
YR -> R     
L  -> epsilon 
R  -> epsilon
```

terminals: 0,1
start: S

Let's split the grammar:

```
S -> LR 
L -> L0Y 
L -> LX
```

This will generate a string in the form `L`, string of `X` and `0Y`, `R`.

```
X1 -> 1X 
X0 -> 0X 
X0 -> 1Y 
Y1 -> 0Y 
YR -> R
```

Treat `X` and `Y` as acting on the binary string: `X` will propagate to the right, then change a `0` to `1` and all subsequent `1`s to `0`s. In effect, a single `X` increments the binary number without changing its string length (or gets stuck).

A leading `Y` will rewrite the string of all `1`s to all `0`s (or gets stuck).

Treat the rules for `L` as the possible actions on the right part of the string. `L => L0Y` will reset the string from all ones to all zeroes and increase its length by one. `L => LX` will increment any other number, but fails if the value is at the maximum.

These two actions together are sufficient to generate (inefficiently) all strings of zeroes and ones (including the empty string).

```
L  -> epsilon 
R  -> epsilon
```

will only clean up the sentinels.

one possible description of the language within four words:

set of all strings